# Thickbox 3.1 IE8 Loading Problem

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, thickbox

We use Thickbox 3.1 for modal windows on our site and noticed recently that it has stopped loading on IE8. You can see the issue by going to http://alltrails.com and clicking "Login" on the top right.

We've been trying unsuccessfully to troubleshoot but can't figure out how to resolve this. I'm hoping someone else has ran into this or knows Thickbox well and can offer a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there any Javascript errors that show up in the F12 developer console?

Comment: Any particular reason to shout like that?

Comment: @Steven - Nothing of note. Any ideas of what might be causing the issue. Seems like FF4 is also having an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ThickBox doesn't have problems with IE8 (you can test it here http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)
You might have some problems in your code, because is not loading in Firefox 4 either (works fine en Chrome)

Have you added a new script recently? Usually the problem is with plug-in clashing between them.

How to troubleshoot the problem:

- Remove the minified ThickBox from all.js
- Add the full version (no minified) of Thickbox
- Use Firebug in Firefox or Dev tools (F12) in and place a breakpoint in the Thickbox script
- Follow to code to see where it fails

**Got it!!**
the problem is in the line 1770 of All.Css

```
.galleria-more{background-image:url(http://static.alltrails.com/images/galleria/info.png');right:30px;}
```

You forgot to open the `'` so no more css after this line is considered in FF and IE (Chrome is more cool on the error)

*Did I get a cookie?*

Comment: We haven't changed our JavaScript recently. I'm not super experienced in troubleshooting JS issues. Any ideas or hunches on what might be causing the issue or where to start?

Comment: Edited with ideas. Apparently is stucked setting the `TB_window` style and inner HTML

Comment: BREAKING: the problem is in the CSS not the JS. _Developing..._

Comment: You are the man! Just updated it and it seems to have done the trick. Amazing catch. Thanks so much for the help.